# Can't access CrUX Dataset on Google BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery, chrome-ux-report

maybe my question is not directly programming related but kind of like pre-programming, because I can't even access the data I want to query and i saw that possible tags exist on here. I'm trying to access the CrUX dataset on Google BigQuery. But all searches on the Google Cloud Console didn't return the dataset. Maybe I'm just looking at the wrong search fields or just can't access it, but it should be publically visible right? I activated my account and also started the trial by providing my payment details. I tried various search patterns (chrome-ux-report, Chrome User, Chrome UX Report, Chrome User Experience Report) in multiple Search fields:

- I tried to search on the Marketplace (without setting filters) but only the Chrome UX Report API is returned here
- Also when I search in Big Query directly, no result is returned. I tried all possible search fields that I found:

  - in the Explorer
  - the +ADD Button
  - the search bar at the top

Maybe sombody can help me here. Thank you in advance for your reply and help!
Best Regards!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow the instructions in the [CrUX documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/bigquery#accessing_the_dataset_in_gcp)

> Using BigQuery requires a [GCP project](https://cloud.google.com/) and basic knowledge of SQL. The [CrUX dataset on BigQuery](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=chrome-ux-report&d=all&page=dataset) is free to access and explore up to the limits of the [free tier](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/pricing#queries), which is renewed monthly and provided by BigQuery. Additionally, new GCP users may be eligible for a [signup credit](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#free-trial) to cover expenses beyond the free tier. Note that a credit card must be provided for the GCP project, see [Why do I need to provide a credit card?](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/frequently-asked-questions#why-credit-card).
>
> If this is your first time using BigQuery then follow below steps to set up a project:
>
> 1. Navigate to [Google Cloud Platform](https://console.cloud.google.com/projectcreate).
> 2. Click Create a Project.
> 3. Give your new project a name like “My Chrome UX Report” and click Create.
> 4. Provide your billing information if prompted.
> 5. Navigate to the [CrUX dataset on BigQuery](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=chrome-ux-report&d=all&page=dataset)
>
> Now you're ready to start querying the dataset.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. I already tried the documentation on the [german version](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/crux/bigquery?hl=de#accessing_the_dataset_in_gcp) of the Guide, but the corresponding [Link](https://console.cloud.google.com/bigquery?p=chrome-ux-report&%3Bd=all&%3Bpage=dataset&hl=de) on this side didn't lead to a console with the dataset. The link on the english version you provided now does. Maybe the link on the german version is broken? With a search on the console I still can't find the dataset, but that isn't bothering me any futher now.

Comment: Hmmm it seems to have put a couple of extra `%3B` symbols in the URL in the German one which breaks it. Thats for letting me know - will raise a bug to get that fixed!

I don't really understand how Search works on the in that "+ Add" feature! If it helps "Star a project by name:" and then can search for `chrome-ux-report` that works too.